# How can I connect php-apache and MySQL using Docker?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, bash, docker

I have a Wordpress site on live server and I want to create a LAMP stack locally with Docker to test things.

I pull the images of `php:7.0-apache` and `mysql:5.7`, the same versions on live.

I create a MySQL container:

```
docker run -d --name achi-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 mysql:5.7
```

I create a php & apache container and link it with MySQL:

```
docker run -d --name achi-php-apache --link achi-mysql:mysql -p 8080:80 -v /home/achi/workspace/web/wordpress-template/:/var/www/html php:7.0-apache
```

I get the following error on localhost:8080:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1564 [...]`

Do I link these two containers the wrong way?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated / removed since PHP 7.0. wordpress version?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch wordpress v4.9.4

Comment: There is also a [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) image that you can try out. Here is a guide that may help: [docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is not the connection between your containers. The problem is your PHP / Apache container which doesn't support [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (or [PDO MySQL](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)). WordPress can't find another function to connect with a MySQL database or your MySQL container. Instead WordPress is using a [deprecated and removed (since PHP 7.0) `mysql_` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) per default. You need to install at least `mysqli` on your PHP container (explained below).

I also recommend to use a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file to install and run all containers with one command.

To create the containers you want, you can use the following [`docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

```
version: "3"

services:
  achi-php-apache:
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: achi-php-apache
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /home/achi/workspace/web/wordpress-template:/var/www/html:rw
    depends_on:
      - achi-mysql
    networks:
      - wp-net
  achi-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: achi-mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp-dbname
    volumes:
      - wp-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wp-net

networks:
  wp-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wp-mysql-data:
```

You need the following `Dockerfile` on the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli
```

This `Dockerfile` installs the missing `mysqli` extension so WordPress can use it.

You can also use PDO MySQL instead of `mysqli`. In this case you can use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql
```

Now you can execute the command `docker-compose up` inside the folder where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located. After creating the container and running you should be able to access the WordPress site (`<ip-or-hostname>:8080`).

On the `wp-config.php` file you need to use the following constants:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wp-dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '123456');
define('DB_HOST', 'achi-mysql');
```

---

You can also use the [official WordPress image](https://store.docker.com/images/wordpress) to install WordPress. In this case you can use the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  achi-php-apache:
    image: wordpress:4.9.4-php7.0-apache
    container_name: achi-php-apache
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: achi-mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 123456
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp-dbname
    volumes:
      - /home/achi/workspace/web/wordpress-template:/var/www/html:rw
    depends_on:
      - achi-mysql
    networks:
      - wp-net
  achi-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: achi-mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp-dbname
    volumes:
      - wp-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wp-net

networks:
  wp-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wp-mysql-data:
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the first method you described (not wordpress image).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use docker-compose to link all your docker instances together rather than linking through the docker command. Here is a sample docker-compose.yml file that should do what you want:

```
version: '2'
services:
  achi-php-apache:
    image: php:7.0-apache
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    volumes:
     - /home/achi/workspace/web/wordpress-template/:/var/www/html
    links:
     - achi-mysql
  achi-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
     - /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_USER: someuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: somedefaultdatabase
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is clean but I'm still getting the same error. Can it be that my php image is missing some functions? I'm using the official 7.0 though.

Comment: Yes, I think it's probably that the you need to update the PHP settings to allow mysql_ functions, but if you can get your wordpress updated to use mysqli_ functions instead that would be more secure.